# How do I vary Width and Height values of view when converting it into a Bitmap?

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

I am using a view instead of Marker to show `LatLng` positions in `google map`. I have a `imageview` and a `textView` in my inflated view.I need to increase my bitmap image size but whatever width and height I give in .xml file, the `getMeasuredHeight()` and `getMeasuredWidth()` always returns 100,50 respectively. How do I vary those values to my need? Where do I change my dimensions so that it reflects in those methods? Thanks in advance!!

**Here is my .xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#e11cc1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgMarker"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_car_image"
        android:layout_height="15dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtHeader"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my MapsActivity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        View markerView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_view,null);


        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        LatLng melbourne=new LatLng(-37,144);
        List<MarkerOptions> markers=new ArrayList<>();
        markers.add(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getBitmapFromView(markerView),"sydney")));
        markers.add(new MarkerOptions().position(melbourne).title("Marker in Melbourne").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getBitmapFromView(markerView),"melbourne")));

        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            mMap.addMarker(markers.get(i));
        }

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

    }


//Method to convert view into a bitmap image
    public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view,String name) {

        view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());  //Here I get only 50 and 100 whatever dimensions I set for my view.

     TextView txtHeader=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
    txtHeader.setText(name);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```